# Como saber quais os nomes das posições do array em php?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu envio do javascript 2 arrays com os seguintes dados:

```
values = {'tipoLicenciamento':tipoLicenciamento,'modulo':modulo} ;
values = {"modulo":modulo,"categoria":6};
```

No meu php eu recebo algo do tipo quando dou um `printr()`

```
Array ( [modulo] => 2 [categoria] = 6)
Array ( [tipoLicenciamento] => 1 [modulo] => 2 )
```

Acontece que tenho 2 botões diferentes para o form, onde cada um gera esse array. Eu consigo saber o nome das posições do array?

Comment: Quer so os nomes da chaves do array?

Comment: "Nome das posições" seria as chaves do *array*? Isto é, em um resultar `modulo, categoria` e no outro `tipoLicenciamento, modulo`? Seria isso?

Comment: exatamente isso anderson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pegar os nome das chaves de um array uma maneira é usar a função `array_keys()`

```
$arr = array('modulo' => 2, 'categoria' => 6, 'tipoLicenciamento' => 3);
$chaves = array_keys($arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($chaves);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => modulo
    [1] => categoria
    [2] => tipoLicenciamento
)
```

Outra forma quando adequada é inverter os valores pelas chaves, `array_fliper()` faz isso. É **importante** comentar que caso existam dois os ou mais valores iguais quem prevalecerá é a última chave no caso `outra`.

```
$arr = array('modulo' => 2, 'categoria' => 6, 'tipoLicenciamento' => 3, 'outra' => 3);
$chaves = array_flip($arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($chaves);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [2] => modulo
    [6] => categoria
    [3] => outra
)
```

Comment: Entendi, eu estava usando o array keys de forma errônea, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

A função que você está procurando (se eu entendi bem), se chama `array_keys()`.

Para usar:

```
<?php

     $keys = array_keys($_POST['nome']);//Armazena nome das posições como um array
     print_r($keys);//Saída: Array ([0] => key [1] => other)
```

Você pode ver mais a respeito na [página dela no php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 2):

Se você já percorre o *array*, você pode obter a chave diretamente com o `foreach`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/f6dD4f).

Obviamente que desta forma só é eficiente se você precisar percorrer o *array*. Se apenas desejar obter a lista de chaves, utilize `array_keys`, como indicado nas outras respostas.